# CSS How To: Easily make all rules check for 1 ancestor

Tags: html, css

For example:

```
.main .box{
    //rules
}
```

These rules will affect all `box` so long as they are inside of a tag of class `main`

Lets say I have about 100 rules on this page and all of them are only to be enforced if inside a tag of class `main`. Is there an easier way to enforce this or do I have to place `.main` in front of every rule in the .css? If there a way to declare this simply at the top of the .css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no". In plain CSS, you will have to put `.main` in front of every rule in the file. The longer answer is "sort of". If you are using a pre-processor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), you can do something like the following:

```
.main {
    .box {
        //rules
    }
    // rinse and repeat
}
```

That said, if this is the only thing you need a pre-processor for, it's likely to be overkill. In many cases, pre-processors can help make your code easier to maintain and write (such as with situations like your example). However, you should evaluate your own needs against the pros and cons to decide whether it makes sense in your case.

Comment: [@the-one-and-only-chemistryblob's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39496963/387928) is the ideal solution if you don't want/need to use a pre-processor.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this....place the same prefix in front of each child class within .main, then use the class or ID attribute "begins with" selector

```
.main [class^="main-prefix"] {}
```

or for IDs

```
.main [id^="main-prefix"] {}
```

The attribute selector is saying that any element that has a class/ID that begins with - you can also place an asterisk in front of the bracket but it is not necessary:

```
.main *[id^="main-prefix"] {}
```

These selectors would apply to classes such as `.main-prefix-box`

Comment: This is the best solution if you do not want to use a CSS pre-processor, but it has the drawback of requiring you to either change or add the classes to both your CSS and HTML.

Comment: Yes, but it is a workable strategy for future web dev projects the OP may have

Comment: I definitely agree. I meant to imply that in lieu of a pre-processor, this is an ideal solution to achieve the OP's goal (since "you can't" is an answer I don't enjoy giving).

Answer (score 1):

You have to put them in front of every rule in the .css.

You can look into css preprocessors like SASS or LESS to make your life easier for these things.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an easy way to declare this for an entire file. You would have to use a preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org) to do that. Which allow you to embed CSS selectors inside of other selectors. But it's either that or putting it in front of ever selector.